# How to change live date?

Tags: mongodb

I wonder, How do I change a live data schema with MongoDB ?

For example If I have "Users" collection with the following document:

```
var user = {
    _id:123312,
    name:"name",
    age:12,
    address:{
        country:"",
        city:"",
        location:""
    }
};
```

now, in a new version of my application, if I add a new property to "User" entity, let us say weight, tall or adult ( based on users year ), How to change all the current live data which does not have adult property. I read MapReduce and group aggregation command but, they seem to be comfortable and suitable for analytic operation or other calculations, or I am wrong.

So what is the best way to change your current running data schema in MongoDB ?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends upon your programming language. MongoDB is really good at having a dynamic schema. I think your pattern of thought at the moment is too SQL related whereby you believe that all rows, even if they do not yet have a value, must have the new field.

The reality is quite different. The rows which have nothing meaningful to put into them do not require the field and you can, in your application, just check to see if the returned document has a value, if not then you can assume, as in a fixed SQL schema, that the value is `null`.

So this is one aspect where MongoDB shines, is the fact that you don't have to apply that new field to the entire schema on demand, instead you can lazy fill it as data is entered by the user.

So just code the field into your application and let the user do the work for you.

The best way to add this field is to write a loop, in maybe the console close or on the primary of your replica (if you have one, otherwise just on the server), like so:

```
db.users.find().forEach(function(doc){
    doc.weight = '44 stone';
    db.users.save(doc);
});
```

That is currently the best way to do something like what your asking.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The fact is that even if I don't need to, I have to ! I need to query by these new properties.

Comment: @Adio MongoDB has a dynamic schema, basically this means that querying by these fields will not raise an error if there is no data there or the field does not exist, more simply that the field will just reutrn null if it has no data in it

Comment: That's it !  I don't want to to return null, I want to have a data ! How can I iterate over the existing data and add whatever I want add to to it ? Is it a task for MapReduce or some other mechanism ?